# change the interspace between UIPageControl dots

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

I would like to change the interspace between the dots in UIPageControl. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no public method to do that. UIPageControl is a really poor customizable class. You can make it one by yourself or take a look in github, there are a logo of different classes similar to page control. Like this [ddpagecontrol](http://www.ddeville.me/2011/01/ddpagecontrol-a-custom-uipagecontrol/)

Comment: The Link to "ddpagecontrol" is broken!

Comment: Using google I've found another reference to the same project http://ddeville.me/2011/01/ddpagecontrol-a-custom-uipagecontrol